# OpenCV Even Rectangles

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to split an image into even rectangles where the number of rows in each rectangle depends on the number of processors in a machine.

My image is 720x601 so on 4 cores my image is split into 4 even rectangles with the dimensions of 180x601. Now I am trying to take each sections with 4 extra rows above and below.

Running my code I get a local start and local stop of
localstart 0 localstop 179
localstart 180 localstop 359
localstart 360 localstop 539
localstart 540 localstop 719

When I take the extra rows above and below my start and stop become
start 0 stop 183
start 176 stop 363
start 356 stop 543
start 536 stop 720

With these values I use the Rect Function

```
cv::Mat tmp = image(cv::Rect(x, start, image.cols, stop));
```

This should gives me 4 section with the dimensions above in terms of start and stop but I get my first section with dimenstion 0x183, the seconds section however gets the dimensions:
183x601
363x601

localstart and localstop are calculated from a method used to create a load balance for work to send to each processor.

```
void parallelRange(int globalstart, int globalstop, int irank, int nproc, int& localstart, int& localstop, int& localcount)
{
    int nrows = globalstop - globalstart + 1;
    int divisor = nrows/nproc;
    int remainder = nrows%nproc;
    int offset;
    if (irank < remainder) offset = irank;
    else offset = remainder;

    localstart = irank*divisor + globalstart + offset;
    localstop = localstart + divisor - 1;
    if (remainder > irank) localstop += 1;
    localcount = localstop - localstart + 1;
}
```

then it crashes with an assertion saying I am out of array bounds.

My code for this is:

```
int start = std::max(0, localstart[irank] - blurLevel);
int stop = std::min(localstop[irank] + blurLevel, image.rows);

cv::Mat tmp = image(cv::Rect(x, start, image.cols, stop));
cout << tmp.rows << "x" << tmp.cols << endl;
img = matToBytes( tmp );
```

I am hoping someone can tell me why when using start/stop my image sections get odd dimensions. I use similar code elsewhere to get 4 even sections.

Comment: It seems like you must just have an assignment bug in your code. Can you post the actual loop code that shows how you calculate `x`, `start` and `stop`? Also at least isn't it a bug to use `image.rows` as your minimum? Shouldn't it be `image.rows - 1`?

Comment: Additionally it looks like you are using `stop` as a row position rather than a height. I thought the Rect signature is `Rect(x, y, width, height)`? Overall please share an [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: x is always 0, since x and y are the image coordinates to start the rectangle section at, I will put in how the localstart and localstop are calculated.

Comment: @KobeJohn I am trying to use stop as a row, since I want to sent a rectangle for processing with padded rows on each side (from start to stop), but I only want to process from n to m within that rectangle

Comment: I'm going to wait until it is an MCVE to review the code. However, assuming that `parallelRange` is calculating correctly, I still think the bug is that you are using `stop` as a row. Isn't this what you want: `Rect(x, start, image.cols, stop-start+1)`?

Comment: I apologize, I dont think I can create the MCVE as I really dont want to post all the code. Your solution gives me the same results as before making me thing the error is elsewhere.